# Actionscript regex false negative

Tags: actionscript-3

The list of words is very long, I cannot paste the actual code that bugs out here.
The regex **whitelist** has approx 4500 words in it seprated by a |

Both the regex, **whitelist** and **whitelist2** includes the word *hello* but the test for each returns different results and I have no idea why after testing the same with javascript which gives correct results.

Here is the actionscript for testing.
The line for **whitelist** might not be visible entirely, try copying pasting the code from the link below in your text/code editor.
http://wonderfl.net/c/jTmb/

Edit1: problem I'm facing is that sometimes the words are not an exact match.
Example saturdays need to match saturday.
Its why I was using regex.

About the string length.
I tried to check the length of the string and its being reported correctly.
http://wonderfl.net/c/a9yp/

Edit2:
Test showing it works in javascript
http://tinyurl.com/m74hmdj

Comment: On some forums I've seen it said that the maximum amount of characters in a line of actionscript is 1022. Maybe that is interfering?

Comment: Oh. I was thinking if it might be some limit on length of a string in actionscript too.
1st day of trying something in actionscript..
Thanks, will take a look at it.

Comment: About string length. You're not likely to hit the AS3 maximum string length - it's 2 gigabytes - can't remember if that's in UTF-16, which would make it at least 1 billion characters.

Comment: Yea, I tested it out, it had not hit a limit.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat Sorry for my question, but Why do you do use a RegEx for find a simple string? I suppose that you are using that, because you need to find a complex pattern?. In other case you could use a String functions to search this word.

Answer (score 1):

Actual answer...

This question led me into finding some interesting AS3 limitations for the first time...

Your regex fails at the length it has by the word "metabrushite". As far as I can tell from various tests, this is where it hits the longest supported length of a regex in AS3: **31391 characters**. Any regex longer than that seems to *always* return `false` on a call to `test()`. Note that "hello" appears in the list before "metabrushite", so it's not a matter of truncation - the regex simply silently fails to work at all - e.g. a regex that should always return `true` for *all* words, still returns `false` if it's that long.

The limit seems a rather arbitrary number, so it's hard to tell exactly what makes this limit.

Again, you should really not be using regex for a task like this, but if you feel you *have* to, you'll need to split it up into several regex'es, each of which don't exceed the maximum length.

**Side note:**

Another interesting thing, which I haven't examined more closely, is that creating the `RegExp` from a single-statement concatenated string, i.e.:

```
trace("You'll never see this traced if too many words are added below.");
var s:String = "firstword|" +
               "secondword|" +
               ... +
               "lastword";
```

... will fail for even shorter resulting strings. This seems to be due to a max length imposed on the length of a single statement, and has nothing to do with regex. It doesn't freeze; it doesn't output an error or even the first `trace`. The script is simply silently excluded from the swf and hence never executed.

Comment: Yea, I tried to do indexOf on that string to find the word hello, which worked but regex still didnt work.
Then I remembered this website for regex testing which was based on flash.. So i experimented with the number of items/length of regex string too.
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
http://pastebin.com/UJzeHTy4
If you put the word hello in the text paragraph and the regex pattern from the pastebin link in the pattern textbox on gskinner.com it accepts only 30707 characters after which it returns false for all.

Comment: The different max numbers we get might indicate that it's the internal representation of the regex that sets the limit, not its string length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking @tsiki is right about the max length of an AS3 regex.

This is really a comment, but since I'd like to include a bit of code, I'm putting it as an answer:

Since you're not using the regex for anything other than a list of words separated by `|`, consider using an array instead. Another advantage of this approach is that it will be quite a bit faster.

```
// This is just a way of reusing your list,
// rather than manually transforming it to an array:
var whitelist:Array = "abasement|abastardize|abastardize|..."
                      .split("|");

// Simply use .toLowerCase() on the input string to make it case insensitive,
// assuming all your whitelist words are lower case.
trace(whitelist.indexOf("hello") >= 0);
```

**ETA: Performance**

Here are some performance comparisons.

- `_array` is pre-initialized to a lower case array of strings, split by `|`.
- `_regex` is pre-initialized to your regex.
- `_search` is pre-initialized to a given word to search for.

I'm using your words up to (and including) words starting with `L` - to get around the max regex length limitation:

The code for each test:

regex.test:

```
_regex.test(_search);
```

array.indexOf:

```
_array.indexOf(_search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
```

loop over array:

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < _array.length; j++)
{
   if (_array[j] == _search)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

**Update:** loop, indexOf (check if search string is substring of item in whitelist):

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < _array.length; j++)
{
   if (_search.indexOf(array[j]) !== -1)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

The AS3 compiler doesn't do any unfair optimization of this simple code (such as skipping executions due to not using the result - it's not all that clever).

10 runs, 1000 iterations each, FP 11.4.402.278 - release version:

```
Method            Search for       Avg.        Min       Max          Iter.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
array.indexOf     "abasement"    0.0 ms       0 ms      0 ms           0 ms
regex.test        "abasement"   18.4 ms      14 ms     22 ms      0.0184 ms
loop over array   "abasement"    0.0 ms       0 ms      0 ms           0 ms
loop, indexOf     "abasement"    0.0 ms       0 ms      0 ms           0 ms

array.indexOf     "hello"       31.1 ms      25 ms     42 ms      0.0311 ms
regex.test        "hello"      326.8 ms     309 ms    347 ms      0.3268 ms
loop over array   "hello"       59.4 ms      50 ms     69 ms      0.0594 ms
loop, indexOf     "hello"       97.4 ms      92 ms    105 ms      0.0974 ms

Avg.  = average time for the 1000 iterations in each run
Min   = Minimum time for the 1000 iterations in each run
Max   = Maximum time for the 1000 iterations in each run
Iter. = Calculated time for a single iteration on average
```

It's quite clear that looping over the array and comparing each value is faster than using a regex. You could do a fair bit of comparison before it would catch up to the time the regex comparison spends. And in any event, we're dealing with fractions of milliseconds for a single lookup - it's really premature optimization, unless you're doing hundreds of lookups in a short period of time. If we *were* talking optimization, a `Vector.<String>` might speed up things slightly more, compared to `Array`.

The main point of this whole thing is that, except for relatively complex scenarios, a regex is unlikely to be more efficient than a tailored parser/comparer/lookup - that goes for all languages. It's designed to be a general purpose tool, not to do things the smartest way in every case (or pretty much any case for that matter).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But as you mentioned, the lowercase is a problem.
Another problem I'm facing is that sometimes the words are not an exact match.
Example saturdays need to match saturday.
Its why I am using regex.

Comment: As mentioned, lowercase isn't a problem, convert the whitelist to lower case, convert the input to lower case, compare. Done. If you're comparing non-exact matches, all the more reason to avoid using regex - such a long regex will become a CPU and memory hog *fast*. But would need more information about your actual requirements to suggest anything.

Comment: The string i'll be going through are approx 100 characters long. The white list is for a swear filter. A while loop without regex takes approx 50-100ms on my quad core. A compiled regex should take shorter time I think.
The actual code goes through one word at a time, if it finds that a particular word in the sentence is in the blacklist, I plan to test it against the whitelist.

Comment: Did you test this in a release player rather than debug? I'll add a comparison to this post.

Comment: I didn't go that far. I'm not an AS developer. I'm a bit annoyed with the chat filter in an MMORPG that blocks words like hello,saturday,spicy.
Just trying to help it get fixed lol. Interesting to stumble upon this bug with as3 tho.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll reduce the number of items in the regex and do some performance testing..

Comment: Thanks for the tests. I noticed lot of the words are really rare and I could just get rid of them to lower the time taken for search.

I'll have to check for variations of the white-listed word too.
Instead of 
if (_array[j] == _search)
can you try this?
if (_search.indexOf(_array[j]) != -1)

Comment: And yeah, there are also quite a few duplicates, and some are already substrings of others. Some you could cleverly combine into a single stem. I've ignored the issue of whether this blacklist/whitelist approach is the best in the first place. May be a better match for a topic on codereview or programmers.stackexchange.com. The main point of this whole thing is that, except for very complex comparisons, a regex is unlikely to be more efficient than a tailored comparison - that goes for all languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the loop, indexOf comparison.
I'll give it a try again.
Oh yea and I just noticed some duplicates right in the middle.
Will run the list through duplicate removers and sort it.